# Android Studio - JDK Problems, Android Studio Meltdown

Tags: java, android, java-8, java-7

After I updated my Java JDK 8 from Update 40 to 45, all of my projects opened with errors. You know, the red letters over code. When I hit "Alt+Enter" it says to Setup JDK. I've tried uninstalling Java and Android Studio and came up with the same result.

I've also tried using Java JDK 7 Update 80 but still come up with the same problems.

Please look at these pictures because I don't think I have done a good job explaining the problem.

[image: Picture 1]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaMar.png

[image: Picture 2]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gc02g.png

Please help me because otherwise I don't see how I can develop android apps anymore. Any help, ANY HELP is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Go into File > Project Structure and see where Android Studio is pulling your JDK from.

Comment: Not sure what I was using before the incident but I tried using JDK 7 and 8 with no success.

Comment: Have you tried installing java on a path with no spaces?

Comment: Never heard of that. Could you explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After uninstalling everything possible and trying various Java versions I found a solution. Java JDK 7 Update 80 works fine with Android Studio.

In my opinion Android Studio should support all versions of Java, but that's just me.