# Android studio - no option to import classes

Tags: java, android, class, android-studio, import

I can not get any android classes to autofill in android studio. All of the android classes appear red ('cannot resolve symbol/method') and there is also no option for me to import class. If I manually enter the code to import the individual classes and compile my code it will run fine, however this is really annoying.

I have tried to 'Invalidate caches/restart'as suggested in other posts but this does not fix my issue. I have also checked updated everything in the android sdk as well as tried reinstalling android studio but nothing has worked.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: which version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: Have you tried settings like, `File->Settings->Editor->General->Auto Import->Insert imports on paste: All` ?

Comment: What classes are you trying to import and use?

Comment: @user370305 i have all 3 auto import options enabled, and insert imports on paste is set to 'all'

Comment: @AmanGrover i am using version 1.2.2

Comment: @TooManyEduardos I am trying to use classes such as Activity, Menu, View etc. Standard android classes

Comment: @DanielNugent when i use _Alt+Enter_ on such a class the only option i get is to _setup JDK_ or _create annotation_.

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  Here is an example of what you should see: http://i.imgur.com/VFSElvA.png?1

Comment: @DanielNugent that is what i see, then when i press Alt+Enter, instead of getting a list of classes, there are no classes, only an option to 'setup jdk' or 'create annotation'

Comment: Looks like you don't have Java set up correctly, or you don't have a compatible version, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29723179/android-studio-jdk-problems-android-studio-meltdown

Comment: Did you do a build using Gradle?