# Android Studio 2.3.3: Does not offer import suggestions

Tags: android-studio

Windows 10, Android Studio 2.3.3

When in my project no import some classes, the Android Studio not offer import options. Also in show errors only "**Messages**" window. But not show red line under incorrect text. Also not work "**Go to declaration**".

I invalidate cache and restart but it not help.

Comment: have you try reinstall ?

Comment: I want to avoid this solution

Comment: [jdk problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29723179/android-studio-jdk-problems-android-studio-meltdown) your problem maybe same as this one

Comment: No. I has jdk 8.0  (install before 1 year) and not update anymore. Before 3 days it's work fine. But today not

Comment: [reset Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384033/how-to-reset-android-studio) well then I guess, you may need to reset your android studio  [youtube reset Android Studio video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AwZEliSPGwU)

Comment: Only resinstall Android Studio fix the problem. I think it's not good.

Comment: btw can you tell me what is the last configuration you set or last program you install make the Android Studio start not working as normally ?

Comment: It's late. I uninstall prev version of Android Studio and install new version.